# How to use a different style of .select2: filter option as first line not in dropdown?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-select2

Instead of clicking on the select2 form input and it showing a drop down menu with a textbox in it:

[image]

How can we show it where the textbox replaces the placeholder text like so:

[image]

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= f.grouped_collection_select(:name, @collection, :last, :first, :to_s, :to_s, include_blank: true ) %>

<script>
  $('#lifetime_name').select2({
    placeholder: "Enter Challenge",
    theme: "bootstrap",
    tags: true,
    multiple: false,
  });
</script>
```

**[Select2 Github](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#placeholders)**

Comment: Galli.com, There is option is select2

Comment: It looks as if this is only achievable by removing the placeholder option.

Comment: point is that you don't want to show the filter option right ?

Comment: @RyanBigg I can't see how a placeholder would be the issue. An example of select2 has a placeholder in it: https://select2.github.io/examples.html#placeholders

Comment: @Venkatraman. I want the filter option. I just want it as the first line and not as part of the dropdown

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com, Check my answer and let us know

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select2 start with input field instead of dropdown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20223044/select2-start-with-input-field-instead-of-dropdown)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you actually expecting here is multi-select or multi-value drop down box in that example. It is not a single value drop down box.

As a workaround. try this below.

```
 $('#lifetime_name').select2({
    placeholder: "Enter Challenge",
    theme: "bootstrap",
    tags: true,
    multiple: true,
  }).on('select2:select', function (e) {
        //clear the input box after a selection is made
        $(this).val([]).trigger('change');
        $(this).val([e.params.data.id]).trigger("change");
    });
```

Refer this Question:
[Select2 start with input field instead of dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20223044/select2-start-with-input-field-instead-of-dropdown)

Comment: Thanks so much Ven! That worked perfectly after toying with CSS to get the desired look.