# Remove selected option from select2 multiselect on change.

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have the following code. The aim is to style a select2 box with textbox as the searchbox. So I have implemented it as multiselect , but I only want one option to be selected.

*One option is to restrict using `maximumSelectionLength: 1`. But in this case the limit message will be shown which i do not want to happen. (Even if i hide it some space will be taken up ).*

*Other option is to hide everything other than `last-child` , in that case multiple values will be send to backend when form is submitted.*

**So is there a way to remove the currently selected value when the new value is selected in multiselect ?**

**I'm using select2 version 3.5.2**

```js
$('#placeSelect').select2({
    width: '100%',
    allowClear: true,
    multiple: true,
    placeholder: "Click here and start typing to search.",
    data: [
            { id: 1, text: "Honolulu"     },
            { id: 2, text: "Tokyo"    },
            { id: 3, text: "Delhi" },
            { id: 4, text: "Zurich"   }
          ]    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/select2/3.4.8/select2.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/select2/3.4.8/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h3>Select a value</h3>
<input type="text" id="placeSelect"/>
```

Comment: You can achieve only one select by multiple: false; Do you face any problem with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only keep the last selected item and remove all other. Like this way :

```js
$('#placeSelect').click(function () { 
   var t = $("#placeSelect").val().substr($("#placeSelect").val().length - 1);
   $("#placeSelect").val(t).trigger("change");
});

$('#placeSelect').select2({
    width: '100%',
    allowClear: true,
    multiple: true,
    placeholder: "Click here and start typing to search.",
    data: [
            { id: 1, text: "Honolulu"     },
            { id: 2, text: "Tokyo"    },
            { id: 3, text: "Delhi" },
            { id: 4, text: "Zurich"   }
          ]    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/select2/3.4.8/select2.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/select2/3.4.8/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h3>Select a value</h3>
<input type="text" id="placeSelect"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('#placeSelect').select2({
    width: '100%',
    allowClear: true,
    multiple: false,
    placeholder: "Click here and start typing to search.",
    data: [
            { id: 1, text: "Honolulu"     },
            { id: 2, text: "Tokyo"    },
            { id: 3, text: "Delhi" },
            { id: 4, text: "Zurich"   }
          ]    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/select2/3.4.8/select2.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/select2/3.4.8/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h3>Select a value</h3>
<input type="text" id="placeSelect"/>
```

Comment: It cannot be done , That was the prime use. In single select the searchbox will appear instead of searching in textbox , i want to search directly in the textbox instead of the select2 custom searcbox.

Comment: see this thread, maybe it can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20223044/select2-start-with-input-field-instead-of-dropdown

Answer (score 0):

You are using a multi option select, I suggest you to do the following:

```
multiple: false,
```

Comment: It cannot be done , That was the prime use. In single select the searchbox will appear instead of searching in textbox.

Answer (score 0):

just add the following code in your query and it will work as you need it

```
$('ul.select2-choices').on("click", function() {
    $("ul.select2-choices li .select2-search-choice-close").click();
  });
```