# Display select2 as plain input text

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, typeahead

I'm using `select2` plugin (latest version 4.0.2) for autocomplete in my probject. I found that `select2` can be applied only to select control. 
The main problem is that text input placed as first option of this control (see img below).

Is there any way to have text input placed instead of select control (like typeahead plugin)?

Some of screenshots (actually you can try it [here](https://select2.github.io/examples.html))

**Collapsed** (you can see here only standard select html control with selected option)

[image]

**Expanded** (text input place as the first option of select control, text input hidden if select collapsed)

[image]

**Typeahead** (applied to directly input text, type query text in the first row that always displayed on the page)

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select2 start with input field instead of dropdown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20223044/select2-start-with-input-field-instead-of-dropdown)

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu, not sure about duplications, but the main difference that select2 version. That question was published in 2013, and I think select2 ver 3.x was actual. But since select2 ver 4.x it's applied only to select html control

Comment: I'm not sure either, because your question is ***unclear***. That's why I said "possible". Besides library version, is there any other difference between what you're asking and the question I linked?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu, just updated question. Also attached some screenshots with comments

Comment: Is this what you need? `$("#yourSelector").select2({ placeholder: "type query here",allowClear: true});` ?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu, input text still appears as the first option and hidden when control collapsed, isn't it?

Answer (score 7):

Hope this is what you're trying to achieve.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#myInputEle').select2({
    width: '100%',
    allowClear: true,
    multiple: true,
    maximumSelectionSize: 1,
    placeholder: "Start typing",
    data: [
            { id: 1, text: "Nikhilesh"},
            { id: 2, text: "Raju"    }
          ]    
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/select2/3.4.8/select2.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/select2/3.4.8/select2.css" />

<input type="text" id="myInputEle"/>
```

Comment: I already tried this trick. I think it might be used as workaround, but I believe that it's possible to implement that option without this trick.

Comment: snippet is broken. please fix it.

Comment: @dikkini Thanks for the comment. Fixed it!

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution -

**STEP 1** select2 code

```
$('#input').select2();
```

**STEP 2**
Add this CSS end of the select2.css -

```
.select2-dropdown--below {
  top: -38px; }
```

Please note : **38px** is your input field height. You need to adjust your input height.

**STEP 3**
If you need to prevent select2 from flipping the dropdown upward

Open

```
select2.js
```

Find

```
var enoughRoomAbove = viewport.top < (offset.top - dropdown.height);
var enoughRoomBelow = viewport.bottom > (offset.bottom + dropdown.height);
```

Replace with

```
 var enoughRoomBelow = true;
 var enoughRoomAbove = false;
```

**Done !**

**DEMO**

Check my customize version here https://codepen.io/gtanim/pen/pWEdQj

Answer (score 2):

The hack with `multiple` works but is not elegant and has design problems. As shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20223044/select2-start-with-input-field-instead-of-dropdown#answer-53022237), an alternative that works exactly as desired is offered by [selectize.js](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js)

Here is a simple [example](https://selectize.dev/docs/demos/single-item-select)

```js
$('#normalize').selectize();
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.15.2/css/selectize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.15.2/js/selectize.min.js"></script>
<select id="normalize">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">Awesome</option>
  <option value="2">Beast</option>
  <option value="3">Compatible</option>
  <option value="4">Thomas Edison</option>
  <option value="5">Nikola</option>
  <option value="6">Selectize</option>
  <option value="7">Javascript</option>
</select>
```